# Добавить закрывающий тег через preg_replace

Tags: регулярные-выражения

На странице есть теги вида

```
<amp-img layout="responsive" width="1080" height="610" src="https://tehnofan.com/uploads/posts/2017-01/1484215265_zotac_geforce_gtx_1080_mini_3.jpg" alt="Zotac GeForce GTX 1080 mini" class="fr-dib fr-draggable">
```

Нужно после каждого такого тега добавить

```
</amp-img>
```

Такое выражение не работает

```
$row['full_story'] = preg_replace( "'fr-draggable\">'si", "fr-draggable\"></amp-img>", $row['full_story'] );
```

Comment: Может так: `$row['full_story'] = preg_replace( "/(\<amp\-img[^>]*\>)/", "$1", $row['full_story'] );` ?

Comment: К сожалению не работает, происходит полная замена тега, на выходе получаю </amp-img> </amp-img>, вот такое выражение $row['full_story'] = preg_replace( "/(\<amp\-img[^>]*\>)/", "</amp-img>", $row['full_story'] );

Comment: Ой, простите, не то. Вот так попробуйте: `$row['full_story'] = preg_replace( "/(\<amp\-img[^>]*\>)/", "$1</amp-img>", $row['full_story'] );`

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, подскажите, а как удалить все теги form (и все внутри них), а также элементы style у дивов?

Comment: С помощью регулярных выражений?

Comment: Да, такое почему то не работает $row['full_story'] = preg_replace( "'%<form\s*[^>]*>.+?</form>%i'","", $row['full_story'] );

Comment: Попробуйте так: `$row['full_story'] = preg_replace("\<form.*\>.+<\/form\>","", $row['full_story'] );`

Comment: К сожалению такой способ удаляет большую часть статьи, а мне нужно удалить это <form method="post" action="" name="dlemasscomments" id="dlemasscomments"><div id="dle-comments-list">
<a name="comment"></a><div id='comment-id-3083993734'></div>
<div id="dle-ajax-comments"></div>
</div></form>

Comment: Я не могу придумать, как сделать

Comment: Попробуй такое регулярное: `/(\<form.*\>).*(?!<\/form\>).*(<\/form\>)/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить ваше регулярное выражение на такое:

```
$row['full_story'] = preg_replace( "/(\<amp\-img[^>]*\>)/", "$1</amp-img>", $row['full_story'] );
```